# My drop down menu wont show even though I put display to block upon hover

Tags: html, css, navbar

The drop-down menu wont work for my navigation. It gets hidden with display:none but upon hovering nothing is shown even though i specified that when the anchor tag containing the UL is hovered over display the child elements as blocked.

html:

```
<body>

    <header id = "M_head">
            <h2><ul>MC</ul></h2>    

    </header>
        <div id="container">

            <nav id="M_nav">
                <ul>
                    <a>NEWS<img class="Nav_down1" src="Nav_down1.png">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>ting1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                    <a>STORE<img class="Nav_down1" src="Nav_down1.png"></a>
                    <a>BLOG<img class="Nav_down1" src="Nav_down1.png"></a>
                    <a>CONTACTS<img class="Nav_down1" src="Nav_down1.png"></a>
                    <a>ABOUT<img class="Nav_down1" src="Nav_down1.png"></a>


                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section id="M_section">
            <div id=Side_sec></div>
            <div id="Side_sec2"></div>
            </section>

            <footer id="M_footer">

            </footer>
        </div>

    </body>
```

css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block; }

#container {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  background-image: url("MircBackground.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; }

#M_head {
  margin: 0px auto;
  color: black;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 4em; }

#M_head ul {
  padding: 0px auto !important;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 5em;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  letter-spacing: -0.08em;
  word-spacing: -0.03em; }

#M_nav ul {
  width: 102.5%;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: .25em;
  padding-bottom: .25em;
  margin-left: -2.6%;
  margin-top: 0em;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table; }

#M_nav ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 3.5em;
  padding-right: 3.5em;
  padding-top: 0.35em;
  padding-bottom: 0.35em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black; }

.Nav_down1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0.625em;
  margin-left: 0.625em;
  margin-top: 0.3125em;
  overflow: none; }

#M_nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: #FFBF00;
  color: white;
  font-shadow: none; }

#M_nav ul ul {
  display: none; }

#M_nav ul > a:hover > ul {
  display: block; }

#Side_sec {
  height: 50em;
  width: 15%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  float: right; }

#M_section {
  height: 50em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: -1em auto;
  border: 2px solid white; }
```

here is the Jsfiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/va06bfav/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}
#container {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  background-image: url("MircBackground.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#M_head {
  margin: 0px auto;
  color: black;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 4em;
}
#M_head ul {
  padding: 0px auto !important;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 5em;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  letter-spacing: -0.08em;
  word-spacing: -0.03em;
}
#M_nav ul {
  width: 102.5%;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: .25em;
  padding-bottom: .25em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
#M_nav ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 3.5em;
  padding-right: 3.5em;
  padding-top: 0.35em;
  padding-bottom: 0.35em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black;
}
.Nav_down1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0.625em;
  margin-left: 0.625em;
  margin-top: 0.3125em;
  overflow: none;
}
#M_nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: #FFBF00;
  color: white;
  font-shadow: none;
}
#M_nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#M_nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 157px;
  top: 34px;
  left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
#M_nav ul a:hover + ul {
  display: block;
}
#Side_sec {
  height: 50em;
  width: 15%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  float: right;
}
#M_section {
  height: 50em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: -1em auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <nav id="M_nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>NEWS<img class="Nav_down1"src="Nav_down1.png">
                 
                </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>ting1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>NEWS<img class="Nav_down1"src="Nav_down1.png">
                 
                </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>ting1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>NEWS<img class="Nav_down1"src="Nav_down1.png">
                 
                </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>ting1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

If you see your code in dev tool you can see that Ul which is your drop down menu is not immediate children of your anchor tag it is placed after anchor tag immediately. The selector you are using is X > Y which selects direct children (please see the [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) for more detailed information about css selector.)

Changes i have made

Changed your markup structure added li in it which was not there earlier and causing the weird behavior of drop down menu which i have mentioned above.

Changed your css selector from X > Y to X X + Y what this selector will do ,It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
}
#container {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    background-image: url("MircBackground.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#M_head {
    margin: 0px auto;
    color: black;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 4em;
}
#M_head ul {
    padding: 0px auto !important;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 5em;
    text-align: left;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 30%;
    letter-spacing: -0.08em;
    word-spacing: -0.03em;
}
#M_nav ul {
    width: 102.5%;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: .25em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    margin-left: -2.6%;
    margin-top: 0em;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
#M_nav ul a {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 3.5em;
    padding-right: 3.5em;
    padding-top: 0.35em;
    padding-bottom: 0.35em;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: black;
}
.Nav_down1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0.625em;
    margin-left: 0.625em;
    margin-top: 0.3125em;
    overflow: none;
}
#M_nav ul a:hover {
    background-color: #FFBF00;
    color: white;
    font-shadow: none;
}
#M_nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#M_nav ul a:hover + ul {
    display: block;
}
#Side_sec {
    height: 50em;
    width: 15%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    float: right;
}
#M_section {
    height: 50em;
    width: 80%;
    margin: -1em auto;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <nav id="M_nav">
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a>NEWS<img class="Nav_down1"src="Nav_down1.png">
                 
                </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>ting1</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it an immediate child because while your solution works when It does not act the way  I want it. First off it takes up the entire space and pushes the other nav bars down instead of only  being within the subsection.

Comment: ok i will edit the answer thought you should not put your drop down menu in anchor tag .

Comment: alright thanks. that brings me to another point if i wrap the sub menu items in only a link and forget about the anchor tags all together and use the direct child selector(>), it works perfectly. Is there some specific attributes assigned to the anchor tag by default that prevents it from being the direct child.

Comment: <ul> is a block element tag, and <a> is an inline element tag - and block element tags should never go inside inline element tags, only the other way around (or inline element tags inside other inline element tags)...

Comment: that makes sense thanks.but in my body i declared everything as block so doesnt the anchor now becomes block?

Comment: i changed the a tags in nav to li and made the necessary adjusments and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much u not only solved this problem for me but cleared up a huge misconception.